# SQL query to find duplicate rows and return both IDs

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of customers:

```
id | name | email
--------------------------
 1 | Rob  | spam@email.com
 2 | Jim  | spam@email.com
 3 | Dave | ham@email.com
 4 | Fred | eggs@email.com
 5 | Ben  | ham@email.com
 6 | Tom  | ham@email.com
```

I'm trying to write an SQL query that returns all the rows with duplicate email addresses but...  I'd like the query result to return the original ID *and* the duplicate ID. (The original ID is the first occurrence of the duplicate email.)

The desired result:

```
original_id | duplicate_id | email
-------------------------------------------
          1 |            2 | spam@email.com
          3 |            5 | ham@email.com
          3 |            6 | ham@email.com
```

My research so far has indicated it might involve some kind of self join, but I'm stuck on the actual implementation. Can anyone help?

Comment: what if there is an email stored several (more than 2) times? how should it be displayed in column "duplicate_id"?

Comment: Is this an actual problem or some random test case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
  orig.original_id,
  t.id as duplicate_id,
  orig.email
from t
  inner join (select min(id) as original_id, email
              from t
              group by email
              having count(*)>1) orig on orig.email = t.email
having t.id!=orig.original_id
```

By the subquery we can find all ids for emails with duplicates.

Then we join the subquery by email and for each one use minimal id as original

UPDATE: http://rextester.com/BLIHK20984 cloned @Tim Biegeleisen's answer

Comment: Sometimes the requested query isn't always the best answer.

Comment: I agree in general and +1 your answer because of the test case. I even forked yours to test mine)

Answer (score 7):

We could handle this using a join, but I might actually go for an option which generates a CSV list of id corresponding to duplicates:

```
SELECT
    email,
    GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY id) AS duplicate_ids
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY email
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Functionally speaking, this gives you the same information you wanted in your question, but in what is a much simplified form in my opinion.  Because we order the `id` values when concatenating, the original `id` will always appear first, on the left side of the CSV list.  Also, if you have many duplicates your requested output could become verbose and harder to read.

**Output:**

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Not exactly the question requirement. It keeps duplicates in a row combining them. If e.g. the duplicates need to be removed it won't work.

Comment: @StanislavL And where did the see the requirement to remove duplicates?

Comment: Requirement is to have 3 rows not 2, and have original id (the first one i guess)

Comment: @StanislavL If the OP has up its sleeve as a follow-up to delete non original records, then you're right and my query is very far from the intended requirements.  From a reporting point of view, i.e. something I would want to hand my boss, I think my answer has some value.

Comment: I wouldn't actually do that.

Comment: @Strawberry If you see me spending inordinate amounts of time on Stack Overflow, then assume the boss didn't like the report and axed me LOL.

Comment: Interesting answer, thanks. I suppose I should have given more real-world info in the question - but yes, ultimately I need to present this information on an index page of a website where each row represents one instance of a duplicate condition that the user can administer.